# Copying Data from one table into another and simultaneously add another column

Tags: sql

I need to copy 3 columns(with values) from one table to another table(this table will be created as new) and  also need to add an extra column in the new formed table. Is it possible only in one sql query?

I thought this might be an answer -

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_TBL(Col1,Col2,Col3,New_Col) AS SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3       FROM OLD_TBL
```

But the confusion is how to assign the data type of that new column? Is it possible with only one single SQL statement?

Comment: What database are you using?  Not all databases support `create table as` syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example using `create table as` syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_TBL AS
    SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, 'Newcol' as Col4
    FROM OLD_TBL;
```

To assign a data type, use `cast()` or `convert()` to get the type you want:

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_TBL AS
    SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, cast('Newcol' as varchar(255) as Col4,
           cast(123 as decimal(18, 2)) as col4
    FROM OLD_TBL;
```

By the way, you can also add the column directly to the old table:

```
alter table old_tbl add col4 varchar(255);
```

You can then update the value there, if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

## MS SQL

You didn't mention your database.

Here is an example for MS SQL

```
SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,'text field' as NEW_COL INTO NEW_TBL FROM OLD_TBL;
```

This query will create new table `NEW_TBL` and add all data from `OLD_TBL` with additional text field NEW_COL. The type of the new field depends on constant type for example if you need INT type you can use `0` instead of `'text field'` constant.

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/70e28/1)

Comment: I would recommend that you always `CAST` or `CONVERT` the new field value to an explicit Datatype and Size. eg. `CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),'text field')`

Comment: Yeah I forgot that actually - Database is Oracle using PL/SQL ! Anyway thanks a lot –

Answer (score 0):

## PostgreSQL

Today I needed to extend a `product` table with a new NOT NULL uuid column with foreign key contraint. So I had to specify an uuid of an existing image, for the new column. I did like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO product 
(  
    SELECT 
        product_id,
        product_name,
        '32b295g3-1337-4792-b1c4-9e3412b07982' as product_image_id 
    FROM oldproduct
);
```